# How to get model number of the phone?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am targeting Android with Delphi XE7. I would like to obtain the model number of the phone. That is, I would like to obtain the information highlighted in this image:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need details programatically for android or what??

Comment: We have now had 4 answers that offer Java code. It is getting a little repetitive. Please can future answerers bear in mind that the question is a Delphi question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
DeviceType := JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.MODEL);
OSName := GetCodename(JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.RELEASE));
OSVersion := JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.RELEASE);
```

There is a sample [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE7/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Snippets/DeviceInfo/). I hope it'll be useful