# C++ Builder: Get the model of an Android Device

Tags: android, c++, c++builder

I'm developing an Android app using C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin. To have a monitoring of devices which use my app, I would like get the name of these devices. Does exist a function to do that?

Comment: Also: [How to get model number of the phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591698/)

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau I didn't search with the correct keywords. Sorry for the duplicate question...

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for the [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html).

With it, you can monitor emulated and real devices. Using the `adb devices` command, you can list all connected devices that are available to you.  Also, the `adb logcat` command outputs a LOT of verbose/warning/error information from your device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I asked. I'm looking for a C++ function in C++ Builder to get the device name directly in the code of my app. When the app is launching, it'll get the name, so the device won't be connected to a computer.